How do I preview collapsed JSDoc comments in Visual Studio?
I am using Visual Studio 2022 v17.9.5 and I have JavaScript files with JSDoc comments that look like this when expanded:

When I collapse the JSDoc comments, they just become a box with three dots and no preview of what the comment is:

However, in C# when using XML Doc comments, collapsing the comments allows you to preview some of the comment text like this:

How can I make the Visual Studio editor do the same for JSDoc comments in JavaScript files?
